# Issues With Mbed & eclipse compiling

Tags: eclipse, path, ide, mbed

Im not entirely sure if iv misunderstood the instructions on https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/tutorials/eclipse.html
where it states

make[1]: arm-none-eabi-g++: No such file or directory, you need to configure Eclipse's PATH (not your OS PATH).

can someone please clarify what i need to do or if im missing something.
To me this is just asking to go to CMD, where gcc ect -> and paste the location into the PATH under enviroment. i still get the error.

-pasted in the location of where arm-none-eabi-g++ in my PATH 
-added C:/cygwin64/bin into my path
installed every single thing under the sun when it comes to mingw/ or anything else remotely connected

```
01:09:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Nucleo_blink_color_led ****
make all 
Compile: main.cpp
make[1]: arm-none-eabi-g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 127
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Where is arm-none-eabi-g++ installed on your system?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q2-update\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe

Comment: Did you add that bin folder to your path?

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Yep adding that doesnt fix it

Comment: Sorry I am a bit out ideas now. I used to edit in Eclipse (Atollic to be precise) and compile mbed from the command line.

Comment: all good, il give it another crack in a day or two and if worse case it still doesnt want to work then il just resign to that haha.